# MongoDB and storing a DateTime field

Tags: javascript, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am running into an odd issue when I store a DateTime field using Mongoid into MongoDB. On the surface of things from the Ruby side, things look okay:

```
irb(main):002:0> dt=DateTime.strptime("12/02/13 13:25:21", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
=> #<DateTime: 0013-12-02T13:25:21+00:00 ((1726142j,48321s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>


irb(main):003:0> dt.day
=> 2
irb(main):004:0> dt.month
=> 12
irb(main):005:0> dt.year
=> 13
irb(main):006:0> dt.hour
=> 13
irb(main):007:0> dt.minute
=> 25
irb(main):008:0> dt.second
=> 21
```

Now when I store this in MongoDB using Mongoid, it gets stored like the following:

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :datetime, type: DateTime

  def set_stuff_up
    self.datetime = DateTime.strptime("12/02/13 13:25:21", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
  end
end
```

When I retrieve this from the database, this is where the issue occurs:

```
> db.foos.findOne().datetime
ISODate("0013-11-30T13:25:21Z")
> db.foos.findOne().datetime.getMonth()
10
> db.foos.findOne().datetime.getDay()
6
> db.foos.findOne().datetime.getYear()
-1887
```

Results are similarly skewed on the Ruby end of things. Me using `findOne()` to retrieve the document here is fine by the way, as there is only one document in the collection:

```
> db.foos.find().size()
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong format string for that date format. A `%Y` is for a four digit year, `%y` is for a two digit year. From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime):

```
%Y - Year with century (can be negative, 4 digits at least)
        -0001, 0000, 1995, 2009, 14292, etc.
...
%y - year % 100 (00..99)
```

You can even see that the year isn't right in your console:

```
=> #<DateTime: 0013-12-02T13:25:21+00:00 ((1726142j,48321s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

and the `dt.year` value:

```
irb(main):005:0> dt.year
=> 13
```

0013 and 2013 aren't quite the same.

You want to say:

```
self.datetime = DateTime.strptime("12/02/13 13:25:21", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
# ------------------------------------------------------------^^
```